# Highchart issue in values and Label text when using 4 axis

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a graph with 4 y axis which is working fine, but when I click the legend values to check individually, I face a problem.

Here I created the sample of my issue:

https://jsfiddle.net/276rv95s/

When you notice that the Label values of Temperature and Constant are mis-placed. I don't know what wrong in my code.

Here is my code:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        zoomType: 'xy'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Sample'
    },
    xAxis: [{
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
            'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
        crosshair: true
    }],
    yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
        labels: {
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2]
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Temperature',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2]
            }
        },

    }, { // Secondary yAxis
        gridLineWidth: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Rainfall',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
            }
        },
        labels: {
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
            }
        }
    }, { // Tertiary yAxis
        title: {
        text: 'Sea',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
            }
        },
        opposite: true
    },{ // 4th yAxis
      gridLineWidth: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Constant',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[3]
            }
        },
        labels: {
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[3]
            }
        },
        opposite: true

    }],
    series: [{
        name: 'Rainfall',
        type: 'column',
        yAxis: 1,
        data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
    }, {
        name: 'Sea-Level Pressure',
        type: 'spline',
        yAxis: 2,
        data: [1016, 1016, 1015.9, 1015.5, 1012.3, 1009.5, 1009.6, 1010.2, 1013.1, 1016.9, 1018.2, 1016.7],
        marker: {
            enabled: false
        },
        dashStyle: 'shortdot',
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' mb'
        }
    }, {
        name: 'Temperature',
        type: 'spline',
        yAxis: 3,
        data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6],
    }, {
        name: 'Constant',
        type: 'spline',
        data: [2, 6, 5, 1.5, 11, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 8.3, 1.9, 2.6],
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems in your code, in the temperature series and Constant series. You need to make sure that each series points to the appropriate yAxis index.

The temperature series is pointing to index 3 (the forth axis), and constant does not have `yAxis` defined, which means it defaults. Therefore, if you change to the following:

```
{
    name: 'Temperature',
    type: 'spline',
    yAxis: 0, //changed this from 3 to 0
    data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6],
}, {
    name: 'Constant',
    type: 'spline',
    yAxis: 3, //added this
    data: [2, 6, 5, 1.5, 11, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 8.3, 1.9, 2.6],
}
```

**API on series.yAxis**: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.yAxis

**Working example**: https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/276rv95s/1/

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.. :)